# Phonegap (online build) app - no internet connection and network status

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

My first jquery mobile app contains elements which needs datas from Internet sources like public Google calendars and Amazon affiliate widgets but it works only when I testing in my chrome browser or on a Kindle Fire device with the html5 app tester. 
If I build android release apk with the online Phonegap, the Kindle and other android device like a Lenovo mobile can't reach the Internet connection in the app. I've read the all of topics in this issue and found the it was proposed to use `<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />` in the config.xml but it was ineffective.
I also put code snippets in the app like:

```
    if (navigator.onLine) {
  $("#ifonline").append("Online");
} else {
   $("#ifonline").append("offline");

}

var isOffline = 'onLine' in navigator && !navigator.onLine;

if ( isOffline ) {
    $("#ifonline2").append("Status: offline");
}
else {
    $("#ifonline2").append("online");
}
```

But the result is nothing. My config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id          = "com.myapp.myapptodo"
        versionCode = "10" 
        version     = "1.0.0" >
    <name>myapp</name>

    <description>
        myapp is very good but can't find that &@ĐäĐ wifi!
    </description>

    <author href="https://mysite" email="mymail">
        Ceatos
    </author>

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
    </feature>

    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager" />
</feature>

    <access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
```

I have a working wifi network and the devices is connected to it. What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the whitelist plugin

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
```

You might need to add this meta tag on the head

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src *  'unsafe-inline'; script-src *  'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

And add this two lines to the config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

Comment: Thank you. There is a small step forward. The online/ofline tests work, they  write "online" instead of nothing. But getting data from the Internet still not working (from google calendar, amazon) only empty spaces there.

Comment: I wrote all the proposed settings into my config.xml and the meta tag also (index.html) and there was an interesting change. "The online status:" -test became empty (no online or offline :) but the google calendar connection started to working. However the Amazon's script not. ( embedded code detail in the index.html: <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?.... ) Who understands this?

Comment: the src can't start with //, it will try to use file://z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?, change it to use http or https as needed

Comment: Another question:  should I add <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"> to the index.html?

Comment: Yes, you have to add that on the index.html

Comment: Thank you and jcarrera also for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

For checking internet connection I use this function:

```
function checkConnection(){
            var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
            if(Connection.NONE==networkState)
                return "<p>No connection</p>";
}
```

For being able yo use it you have to add the network state plugin this way:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
```

Your AndoidManifest file should include this two lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried your tips but still the same.
I have    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" /> in the config.xml and I created the AndroidManifest.xml containing the two lines also from your post in the directory where the index.html is.
Your example is for local phonegap build but I tried with online build. It seems I will intall phonegap and build my app locally. :(

Comment: Did you add this: `<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />` to your `config.xml` as instructed ?