# Ajax calls not working in cordova 8 when I build my apk

Tags: ajax, cordova, android-studio, phonegap

now I'am developing a app in cordova 8, I have calls with ajax to my server but this calls not working, I have whitlist configurated and the meta tag too.

This is my configuration for whitelist:

```html
<access origin="http://myserver.com" />
<access origin="https://maps.googleapis.com" />
<access origin="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
<access origin="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
<access origin="https://maps.gstatic.com" />
<access origin="https://ssl.gstatic.com" />
<access origin="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />

<!-- and my meta tag -->

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' http://myserver.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://fonts.googleapis.com https://maps.gstatic.com data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src *">
```

And, I tried build the apk in build.phonegap.com and here work it good.

Do you know how to build the apk in Android Studio SDK and fix the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: the one you build on build.phonegap.com is a dev build or a release build? your problem is probably a bad server certificate (or not correctly configured)

Comment: Hi, no, Is a decir build, when I generated build test with phonegap app I have not this problem, also I tryed use from browser and have not problem too. So I think that my server not Is the problem.

Comment: When it works in debug and doesn't work in release is 99% of times a server problem. Just because it works on browser doesn't mean the server is ok. Not all certs errors affect the devices in the same way, so it can work on some and not in others, even work in some Android versions and not in others.

Comment: Ok, but remember that I said that when I builded apk from build.phonegap.com I have not this problem, so I think that the server not is the problem.

Comment: I asked if it was a debug or release build and it's not clear what your answer it to that. You said "Is a decir build". And also the "when I generated build test with phonegap app" is not clear neither. If you are testing in Phonegap Developer app it can work for other different reasons, so you can't trust your own app will work the same way.

Comment: Yes, it`s a dev build. Also I tryed generate the apk in https://build.phonegap.com/, in this website the apk work good.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32943246/7189547

Comment: Guys, sorry, I had my Android Studio outdated, I uninstalled all and re installed and work good. So sorry really. You can close this?