# Using a remote database with PhoneGap using HTML, JS and PHP

Tags: javascript, database, angular, phonegap

I'm facing some difficulties with my PhoneGap app. I want to use an external MySQL database where I allowed remote access. It's working properly in my browser with the remote ip address. When compiling with PhoneGap and installing, it appears that the connection does not work properly. I'm using HTML and Angular on the front with PHP on the backend for the inserting/reading.

Here's my login.js:

```js
angular.module('postLogin', [])
.controller('PostController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) { 
        this.postForm = function() {
            var encodedString = 'username=' +
                encodeURIComponent(this.inputData.username) +
                '&password=' +
                encodeURIComponent(this.inputData.password);

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://78805.ict-lab.nl/keuze_eind/api/auth_login.php',
                data: encodedString,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            })
            
            .success(function(data) {
                    //console.log(data);
                    if ( data.trim() === 'correct') {
                        window.location.href = 'home.php';
                    } else {
                        $scope.errorMsg = "Username and password do not match.";
                    }
            }) 
        }
}]);
```

auth_login.php:

```
<?php 
require_once '../config.php';

global $dbc;

$stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT id,username,email,password from k_users WHERE 
username='".$_POST['username']."' && password='". $_POST['password']."'");

$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->rowCount();

if ($row > 0){    
    echo 'correct';
} else{ 
    echo 'wrong';
}

?>
```

config.php:

```html
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

//connect to MySql database
try {
    $dbc=new PDO("mysql:host=185.224.**.**;dbname=admin","admin_keuze","***") 
     or die("Kon geen verbinding maken met de database.");
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

```
PhoneGap config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id.       = "1.0.0" >

        <name>KnipKappers</name>

        <description>
            De app voor voor KnipKappers.
        </description>

        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~2" source="npm" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" spec="~2" source="npm" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" spec="~2" source="npm" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~4" source="npm" />

        <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.1.0" />

   <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm"/>

   <access origin="*" subdomains="true" />

    </widget>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "it appears that the connection does not work properly"? Do the requests from your PhoneGap app reaches your backend? Are there any errors in your backend? How did you identify that the issue is with the database?

Comment: You can use Remote debugger with https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/ for inspect real apps

Comment: Try to use `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />` instead `<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm"/>`

Comment: You miss few lines to.. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32943246/7189547) example